# How to create instance of a class which has a protected constructor in C#

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Activator.CreateInstance with private sealed class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/440016/activator-createinstance-with-private-sealed-class)

I am trying to access methods in a class which has a protected constructor. Can anyone help me how to create an instance of the class to access methods inside it.

Thanks,

Karteek Kuncham

Comment: Post some code, this question is var too vague.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you can create a subclass of the class you describe. All that is required is you create a constructor in your own class which calls base() with whichever constructor arguments you need.

```
public MyDerivedClass : OtherBaseClass
{
    MyDerivedClass() : base()
    { }
}
```

Comment: i have tried using derived class, but the constructor takes an argument which i have no idea of.

Comment: What does this mean? No one is going to be able to tell you what arguments to pass to some constructor which you have not provided or described in any way.

Answer (score 3):

Class with protected constructor is not accessible to outside world, whereas accessible to its derived classes. If you want to create an instance of those Derived classes then you can but if you want to create the instance of that Base class then you can introduced some static method of Base return type, which can return new instance of your class every time you call Instance method, similar to Singleton pattern, but not restricting to just one instance creation.

**First way:**

```
public Base
{
    protected Base() { }
}

public Derived : Base
{
    public Derived() : Base() { } 
}
```

Usage:

```
Dervied d = new Derived();
```

**Second Way:**

```
public Base
{
    protected Base() { }

    public static Base Instance() { return new Base(); }
}
```

Usage:

```
Base b = Base.Instance();
```

Comment: i have tried using derived class, but the constructor takes an argument which i have no idea of. And i cant change anything in that class as its inside a dll file which comes with a software application.

Comment: But what you can do is, create a parameterized constructor with the argument that constructor needs like public Derived() : Base(string a) { }. Have a reference from this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5142002/how-can-i-get-parameterized-constructor-data-of-base-class-in-child-class-if-chi

Answer (score 1):

Classes with protected constructors are on classes that usually have some form of static method on them that returns instances.

Answer (score 0):

Is the class an abstract class ? 
if yes, then I believe the right thing to do is to inherit that class.